# Oracle to_char bug

Tags: sql, oracle, date, format, to-char

I don't know if it's a bug or what, but when I try to format the Day of the week in a certain way with the to_char function in Oracle, SQL Plus give me this error : ORA-01821: date format not recognized

Here's the line that cause a problem

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dsp') from dual;
```

So d is of 'Day of the week' and sp is for spell.
This line should print five because we are thursday.

It's weird because this next line worked

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'ddsp') from dual;
```

dd is for 'Day of the month' so sql plus printed twenty-nine without any problem!!

Can someone tell me why this line is not working?

Thanks..

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10G express :)

Comment: The sp option to have it spell it out was new to me so I decided to try it out. On Oracle 9i Enterprise 9.2.0.7.0 "select to_char(sysdate, 'dsp') from dual;" gives the result you expected. Unfortunately I do not know why it is not working for you.

Comment: Works fine for me (11.2)

Comment: I'm using Oracle 10G enterprise (10.2.0.3.0) and get the same behavior as you, Joel

Comment: Fails for me (I can repeat the OP issue) on 10.2.0.4. Perhaps a 10g issue?

Comment: I also just tried it out on Oracle 10g enterprise 10.2.0.4.0 - and received the ORA-01821.

Comment: Another interesting note: the 'dthsp' and 'dth' format models work.

Comment: I know...'dthsp' work...I just tried it earlier.

Comment: I can also confirm the bug (10.2 XE). It seems like `'dspth'` doesn't work either, although `'dthsp'` does

Comment: I get the same error, in 10g. So this may be a bug introduced in 10g that was fixed in 11g.

Comment: 11g and 11g Express both work. Upgrade! ;)

Comment: @maz, not always an immediate option ;-)

Comment: @DCookie For Express it is, its kind of home edition anyway :)

Comment: @maz, there may be hoops to jump thru in a production environment

Comment: Thats my point - nobody uses Oracle Express in prod. Its a stripped down development version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must make this work, here's an ugly workaround:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(to_char(SYSDATE,'d'),'j'),'jsp') FROM dual;
```

Looks like a bug to me...